# Is there a database administrator's guide for building stored procedures for Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, orm

I'm working on a green-field application that has a corporate mandate that Stored Procedures are used for all database interaction.

I'd like to use Entity Framework and leverage Stored Procedure Mapping to gain the benefits of the ORM.

Since we will be developing the database and .NET application in parallel, I'm looking for information to help the database developer/administrator. Does anyone know of a consolidated guide on how to design tables and stored procedures so they can be best integrated with the Entity Framework?

A couple tips I've collected are:

- Update Stored Procedures require exactly 1 parameter per table column
- There must be an insert, update, and delete Stored Procedure for every table

I want to know as much about how the database should be designed for easy use with Entity Framework because the database is very difficult to change later in our environment.

Comment: This is a _great_ question, but I'm not sure it's a fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What would be a more appropriate site for it in your eyes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post describing the limitations of using mapping in this way after working on this for several months:

[The Pitfalls of Mapping the Entity Framework to Stored Procedures](https://blog.yeahstu.com/2013/10/13/the-pitfalls-of-mapping-the-entity-framework-to-stored-procedures/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Stored Procedures are used for all database interaction, I just don't see the need to use Entity Framework. One good reason of EF is to save time to write T-SQL, and if you don't take advantage of this, why even use EF?

Comment: `One good reason of EF is to save time to write T-SQL`. It's one good reason, but not the only one! @YeahStu will gain other benefits like not to have to write its own Data Layer and rely on a strong DAL instead. It would be possible for his team to create a real domain model using the EDM designer and map CRUD operations with SP. Sometimes it's just not possible to deal with anything but SP. And I don't see any valid reason why people in that case should avoid any ORM. They will have an opportunity to learn a nice tool and it might be a way to convince their DBAs ;-)